# Sorting worksheets in Excel with VBA using names as dates

Tags: excel, sorting, vba, excel-2007

I am writing a custom sorting procedure for my Excel spreadsheet that has at least 3 worksheets. On first position I put the worksheet called "Summary", on second goes "Data" and the rest are worksheets whose names are dates ex "17.03.2011", "20.03.2011" etc. Those need to be sorted chronologically.

<strike>Here is what I have so far, the script stops with an "Object Required" error on line with the DateDiff() and I have no idea why:
After correcting the code below I am still having trouble in making the thing sort in the right order. Can anyone suggest a way to compare and move around the sheets?</strike>

```
Public Sub ssort()
sSummary.Move before:=Worksheets.Item(1)
sData.Move after:=sSummary
Dim i, n As Integer
Dim diff As Long
Dim current, other As Worksheet

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    Set current = Worksheets.Item(i)
    If current.Name <> sData.Name And current.Name <> sSummary.Name Then

        For n = i + 1 To Worksheets.Count
            Set other = Worksheets.Item(n)
            diff = DateDiff(DateInterval.day, Format(current.Name, "dd.mm.yyyy"), Format(other.Name, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
            If diff > 0 Then
                current.Move before:=other
                Debug.Print "Moving " & current.Name & " before " & other.Name
            ElseIf diff < 0 Then
                current.Move after:=other
                Debug.Print "Moving " & current.Name & " after " & other.Name
            End If
        Next n

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

<strike>I think I either don't understand DateDiff() or Format(), could anyone please shed some light on this?</strike>

After modifying code from an online example here http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=72 to use the datediff for comparison, I came up with this solution which works as intended:

```
Sub sort2()
sSummary.Move before:=Worksheets.Item(1)
sData.Move after:=sSummary
Dim n As Integer
Dim M As Integer
Dim dsEnd, lowest As Integer
Dim dCurrent() As String
Dim dOther() As String
Dim diff As Long
dsStart = 3
dsEnd = Worksheets.Count

For M = dsStart To dsEnd
    For n = M To dsEnd
        If Worksheets(n).Name <> "Summary" And Worksheets(n).Name <> "Data" And Worksheets(M).Name <> "Summary" And Worksheets(M).Name <> "Data" Then
            dCurrent = Split(CStr(Worksheets(n).Name), ".")
            dOther = Split(CStr(Worksheets(M).Name), ".")
            diff = DateDiff("d", DateSerial(dCurrent(2), dCurrent(1), dCurrent(0)), DateSerial(dOther(2), dOther(1), dOther(0)))
            If diff > 0 Then
                Worksheets(n).Move before:=Worksheets(M)
            End If
        End If
    Next n
Next M

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Post the complete code. What is sSummary at the beginning?

Comment: Its a part of a larger codebase, posting all would be too much. sSummary and sData are global variables providing access to "Summary" and "Data" worksheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateDiff` function requires the two date arguments to be of `Variant (Date)` type. Instead you're giving it two `String` arguments, which is what the `Format` function returns.

You need to convert each of the Strings to `Variant (Date)`. This can be done like this:

```
strDate = current.Name ' String: "20.03.2011"
aintDateElements = Split(strDate, ".") ' Array: {2001, 03, 20}
varDate = DateSerial(aintDateElements(2), aintDateElements(1), 
    aintDateElements(0)) ' Variant (Date)
```

There are other ways of doing this conversion, but I find that this is the way that least often gives unexpected results!

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem of comparing dates and getting an integer difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you took this code off of the web, be aware that DateInterval isn't a native Excel object or a VBA object, it's a .Net object.  You could just substitute "d" for "DateInterval.day".

```
diff = DateDiff("d", Format(current.Name, "dd.mm.yyyy"), _
                Format(other.Name, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting error messages in Format/Datediff calls, try split them into separated statements. You'll see where the problem lies.

Example:

```
        dtStart = CDate(Format(current.Name, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
        dtEnd = CDate(Format(other.Name, "dd.mm.yyyy"))

        diff = DateDiff("d", dtStart, dtEnd)
```